# Define and redefine a matrix in Clojure

Tags: matrix, clojure

I would like to define a matrix in memory using Clojure and then change it when I reach a route. From my understanding, I need to create this matrix globally and then change it when I reach that part of the code.

However, since I am new on Clojure, I am not sure how is the best approach to do it. Follow my code:

```
(def global-matrix nil)


(defn create-matrix
  [{:keys [params] :as request}]
  (println global-matrix)
  (var-set global-matrix [[0 0 0] [0 0 0]])
  (println global-matrix)
  (ring-resp/response {:matrix global-matrix})))
```

I am getting a casting problem with this approach so not sure how is the best Clojure solution for this (maybe I am thinking in a not functional programming way).

Comment: Why are you trying to change `global-matrix`? Either it should be immutable and you locally work with modified copies of it, or if you *really* need mutation, you could make it an atom and `reset!` it. Clojure is highly functional leaning though, and most of the time, immutable structures are the most appropriate. I've never used Ring, so I can't make any suggestions regarding it unfortunately.

Comment: I need to create a REST API to change this matrix everytime it is called. There is no way to persist this matrix in memory without defining as a variable right? I got it is immutable but how could I change it then? @Carcigenicate

Comment: Make `global-matrix` an `atom` holding an immutable structure (like a vector of vectors), and `swap!` or `reset!` the `atom` to change it. `atom`s are mutable containers for immutable values.

Comment: An atom is an effective way to do this. You would just do ```(def global-matrix (atom nil))``` and then in your function, do ```(ring-resp/response {:matrix (reset! global-matrix [[0 0 0] [0 0 0]]})```. This is one way to do it but not necessarily the best way. Instead of binding the matrix to a var, you could pass it in the request map and then do ```(ring-resp/response {:matrix (reset! (:matrix request) [[0 0 0][0 0 0]])})```

Comment: The `(!reset variable value)` resets the value globally once the variable is globally? I am trying to call another function after resetting it and the value of the matrix still as `(atom nil)`.

Comment: @andrehigher This expression: ```(let [global-matrix (atom nil)]
        (reset! global-matrix [[0 0 0] [0 0 0]])
        (deref global-matrix))``` evaluates to ```[[0 0 0] [0 0 0]]```. Does it evaluate to the same on your computer?

Comment: Are you planning to use some ready made matrix libraries like clojure.core.matrix?

Comment: Perfect! It is working fine now. Thanks guys!